# Conditional type hint

Tags: python

Im using a pattern that all my adapters returns a `Result` objects instead of the result itself. Let me explain:

```py
from typing import Generic, Optional, TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel


Dto = TypeVar("Dto", bound=BaseModel)


class Result(BaseModel, Generic[Dto]):
    error: Optional[Exception]
    data: Optional[Dto]

    @property
    def is_success(self) -> bool:
        return bool(self.data) and not self.error

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True

def adapter_example(input: Any) -> Result[int]:
    try:
        # some complex stuff here
        result = Result[int](data=10)
    except SomethingBad as e:
        return Result[int](error=e)
```

The point is, check if `error is None` do not ensures me that `data != None`. There is a way to force that at least (and conditionally) one of them are mandatory (or, not `Optional`)?

Like:

```py
Result[str](data='a')                       # VALID
Result[str](error=Exception())              # VALID
Result[str](data='', error=Exception())     # VALID
Result[str]()                               # INVALID

if result.data:
    # Here any linter are 100% sure that result.error is None
else:
    # Here any linter  are 100% sure that result.error != None
```

> ps: Im only using pydantic.BaseModel here because its easier in this implementation. If any sugestions about how to type this class conditionally dont use pydantic is fine to mee

Comment: It was a typo, I fixed it in the example

Comment: Instead of two separate attributes, how would Pydantic go about supporting a single attribute whose type is `Dto | Exception`?

Comment: Hmmm, sounds interesting. So the porperty `is_success` would validate something like `if isinstance(self.data, Dto)` or something. Ill try it and checks if it works

Comment: Also, check out Pydantic's support for [discriminated unions](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#discriminated-unions-aka-tagged-unions), though that may only be useful when instantiating `Result` rather than consuming a `Result` value.